# sudo ./ command not found

Tags: command-line, drivers, gnome-terminal

I am trying to install displaylink driver for docking station D6000.

I downloaded the driver from:

https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Once downloded I have a file named `displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151.run`
As part of installation I already did `sudo apt-get install dkms` but when I go to my extract directory and run command
`sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151.run`

I get the error:

```
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151.run: command not found
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You have to make the file executable before running it. Did you? Easy way is right-click > Properties > permissions...

Comment: Thank you. That was it.